# Problema con queryset en Django: ¿Cuándo eliminar la información temporal?

Tags: python, django

Mi programa consiste en un asistente virtual que responde a preguntas formuladas por visitantes de un sitio web. Entre ellas puede haber ambigüedades, algunas de las cuales se resuelven dando una serie de opciones al visitante.

La siguiente vista de Django me da un problema, ya que uso queryset para cargar  las opciones en la base de datos y mostrarlas por pantalla, y en teoría debería eliminar esas opciones para la siguiente pregunta con esta linea de código:

```
ModelOpciones.objects.all().delete()
```

El caso es que si escribo esa linea de código fuera de la vista, como aquí:

```
ModelOpciones.objects.all().delete()

def AV(request):
    print ('ENTRA EN AV')
    titulo = 'Pregunta a Miguel'
    form1 = RegistradoForm(request.POST or None)
    op = 0

    context = {
        'op': op,
        'tit1': titulo,
        'form1': form1,
    }

    if form1.is_valid():
        pregunta = form1.cleaned_data.get('pregunta')
        salida = main(pregunta)
        if isinstance(salida, str):
            context = {
                'op': op,
                'tit1': titulo,
                'form1': form1,
            }
        else:
            Preg = salida[0]
            Opcs = salida[1]
            op = 1
            for i in range(len(Opcs)):
                ModelOpciones.objects.update_or_create(opciones = Opcs[i])               
            form2 = OpcionesForm(request.POST or None, field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all())

            context = {
                'op': op,
                'tit1': titulo,
                'pregunta': Preg,
                'form1': form1,
                'form2': form2,
            }

            if form2.is_valid():

                opcion = str(form2.cleaned_data['Campo_Opciones'])
                if len(salida) == 5:
                    RespFinal = Respuesta_Opc (Opcs, opcion, salida[2], salida[3], CSin, salida[4])

                else:
                    RespFinal = Respuesta_Amb (Opcs, opcion, salida[2])
                op = 2
                context = {
                    'op': op,
                    'tit1': titulo,
                    'form1': form1,
                    'form2': form2,
                    'RespF': RespFinal,
                }
    return render(request, "AV.html", context)
```

en la siguiente pregunta, se añaden las opciones actuales con las anteriores, como se ve en esta imágen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consola:

Entra 1 vez en AV al abrir el pop-up, 2 veces en el proceso de la consulta "subdirector" y 2 veces en el de "coordinador"

Y si la escribo dentro:

```
def AV(request):
    print ('ENTRA EN AV')
    titulo = 'Pregunta a Miguel'
    form1 = RegistradoForm(request.POST or None)
    op = 0

    context = {
        'op': op,
        'tit1': titulo,
        'form1': form1,
    }

    if form1.is_valid():
        pregunta = form1.cleaned_data.get('pregunta')
        salida = main(pregunta)
        if isinstance(salida, str):
            context = {
                'op': op,
                'tit1': titulo,
                'form1': form1,
            }
        else:
            Preg = salida[0]
            Opcs = salida[1]
            op = 1

            ModelOpciones.objects.all().delete()

            for i in range(len(Opcs)):
                ModelOpciones.objects.update_or_create(opciones = Opcs[i])               
            form2 = OpcionesForm(request.POST or None, field1_qs = ModelOpciones.objects.all())

            context = {
                'op': op,
                'tit1': titulo,
                'pregunta': Preg,
                'form1': form1,
                'form2': form2,
            }

            if form2.is_valid():

                opcion = str(form2.cleaned_data['Campo_Opciones'])
                if len(salida) == 5:
                    RespFinal = Respuesta_Opc (Opcs, opcion, salida[2], salida[3], CSin, salida[4])

                else:
                    RespFinal = Respuesta_Amb (Opcs, opcion, salida[2])
                op = 2
                context = {
                    'op': op,
                    'tit1': titulo,
                    'form1': form1,
                    'form2': form2,
                    'RespF': RespFinal,
                }
    return render(request, "AV.html", context)
```

ocurre lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Consola:

Entra una vez en AV cuando abro el pop-up, una al enviar la pregunta y otra al enviar la opción.

models.py:

```
class ModelOpciones(models.Model):
    opciones = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.opciones
```

forms.py:

```
class OpcionesForm(forms.Form):
    Campo_Opciones = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = ModelOpciones.objects.none(), widget=forms.RadioSelect, empty_label=None)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = kwargs.pop('field1_qs')
        super(OpcionesForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['Campo_Opciones'].queryset = qs
```

AV.html:

```
{% load staticfiles %}
{% if op == 0 %}

{% if form1 %}
<h3> Pregunta a Miguel <a href="." ><img src="{% static "AV.png" %}" alt="AV"></a></h3>
<form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form1.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='Enviar'>
</form>

{% endif %}

<h3>{{ salida|linebreaksbr }}</h3>

{% endif %}

{% if op == 1 %}

{% if form1 %}
<h3> Pregunta a Miguel <a href="." ><img src="{% static "AV.png" %}" alt="AV"></a></h3>
<form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form1.as_p }}
{% endif %}

<h3>{{ pregunta }}</h3>

{% if form2 %}
<form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form2.as_p }}
<input type='submit' value='Enviar'> 
</form>

{% endif %}

{% endif %}

{% if op == 2 %}

{% if form1 %}
<h3> Pregunta a Miguel <a href="." ><img src="{% static "AV.png" %}" alt="AV"></a></h3>
<form method='POST' action=''> {% csrf_token %}
{{ form1.as_p }}
{% endif %}

{% if form2 %}
{{ form2.as_p }}
{% endif %}

<h3>{{ RespF|linebreaksbr }}</h3>

{% endif %}
```

No he subido las imágenes de la consola porque solo se me permite subir 2 imágenes por no tener mínimo 10 de reputación. Espero que haya quedado claro el problema.

He buscado soluciones por toda la documentación de queryset, pero no he encontrado nada, espero que me podáis dar alguna idea.

Un saludo:

Miguel.

Comment: Bienvenido a Stack Overflow en Español. Por favor toma el [recorrido del sitio](http://es.stackoverflow.com/tour). Espero que la comunidad te pueda dar respuestas.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio! Vengo ya del sitio en inglés, y hace poco descubrí que existe versión en español. Que grata sorpresa :D Un saludo!

Comment: Pero porque te complicas la vida y no usas el widget [`select`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/forms/widgets/#select) o agregas un poco de [magia a tu formulario](http://django-autocomplete-light.readthedocs.io/en/master/tutorial.html). El uso de un control `select` reduce en gran medida la posibilidad de error.  En todo caso, la pregunta  me parece muy amplia... o tal vez no está clara y por eso no la entiendo.

Comment: Hola toledano, he cambiado el widget "RadioSelect" por uno "Select" pero el problema persiste. El problema es que al usar un queryset  como soporte para almacenar las opciones, las opciones quedan ahí hasta que no se eliminen con la orden `ModelOpciones.objects.all().delete()`. El caso es que por algún motivo que no comprendo, cuando la uso dentro de la vista, da la impresión que elimina las opciones cuando están "En uso" y cuando el usuario selecciona una y envía "Ya no están". Sospecho que está relacionado con que el flujo del programa pasa varias veces por la vista desde el principio...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

¡Ya encontré una solución!

Consiste en añadir esta línea de código en la vista:

```
ModelOpciones.objects.exclude(pk__gt=(ModelOpciones.objects.last().pk - len(Opcs))).delete()
```

justo después de la creación de objetos con las opciones:

```
for i in range(len(Opcs)):
    ModelOpciones.objects.update_or_create(opciones = Opcs[i])
```

De esta forma, usando el pk único del último objeto y restándole el número de opciones (objetos) actuales, llego al punto exacto a partir del cual debo excluir del borrado las opciones actuales. Así se eliminan exclusivamente las sobrantes y no se generan problemas.

Agradezco vuestras respuestas y especialmente a Soleronline por haberme dado la clave (primaria :P) del asunto ;)

Un saludo:

Miguel.

Answer (score 1):

Buenas, el problema viene dado porque estas eliminando todos los registros de la tabla y generando otros, y los pk seguramente no te coincidan.

El queryset de borrado debería excluir el pk seleccionado en el formulario y luego asegurarse de no volverlo a agregar.

El queryset quedaría algo así:

```
ModelOpciones.objects.exclude(pk=VALOR_DEL_FORMULARIO).delete()
```

Espero que te sea de ayuda

Un saludo

Comment: ¡Gracias Soleronline! Entiendo tu solución, he buscado información sobre el "pk" y según lo que he entendido, es un campo implícito del formulario que identifica cada registro como único, y se asigna en orden de creación, por lo tanto, siguiendo tu solución, he escrito esta línea de código que en teoría eliminaría los registros creados en la consulta precedente: `ModelOpciones.objects.exclude(pk__gte=(ModelOpciones.objects.count() - len(Opcs))).delete()`. Desgraciadamente siguen apareciendo esos registros en la solución, como en la primera imagen... ¿He entendido mal el concepto de pk?

Comment: Lo has entendido bien, pero creo que el fallo sigue siendo que estás borrándolo. Prueba con excluir aquellos pk mayor o igual al pk seleccionado (ese ok viene en el formulario). Saludos

Comment: Creo que estoy más cerca de la solución... cuando me has escrito que el "pk" viene en el formulario he hecho `print ('FORM2 = ', form2)` y al ejecutar el programa, en la consola me ha aparecido información interesante: `FORM2 =  <tr><th><label for="id_Campo_Opciones_0">Campo opciones:</label></th><t
d><ul class="errorlist"><li>This field is required.</li></ul><ul id="id_Campo_Opciones"><li><label for="id_Campo_Opciones_0"><input id="id_Campo_Opciones_0" name="Campo_Opciones" type="radio" value="375" /> Subdirector de Ordenación Académica e Innovación Docente</label></li>...` y demás opciones

Comment: (...continúo) Por una parte, desgraciadamente no encuentro información relacionada al "pk", pero por otra, he probado a discriminar por otros campos y he recibido un error que me indica que solo hay 2 campos posibles: "id" y "opciones". Ese "id" no es el id del "input", pero he descubierto el campo "opciones" en la definición del modelo "ModelOpciones" cuyo código está en el post. ¿Hay otra forma de obtener el "pk" o el "id"? ¿Debería alternativamente crear otro campo en el modelo? ¡Gracias por tu paciencia!